# Using Python/Django how do I substitute values from an external source into an HTML page

Tags: python, html, django

I am relatively new to Django and am trying to substitute values from an external source into an HTML page?

Using the following HTML snippet:

```
        <div>UID: -3SDfguwvNuurPe44AnUjGdzOj_guWVP3QPjmhZyWsA1</div>
        <div>Validic ID: 5e220365bdb13500b03075a2</div>
        <div>Created: 2020-01-17T18:56:37Z</div>
        <div>Updated: 2020-01-17T18:56:37Z</div>
```

I want to replace the text value for each of those rows (to the right of the "key:" with the value retrieved from a JSON response for each of the "keys".

I have tried:

````
        <div>UID: {{ display_uid }}</div>
        <div>Validic ID: {{ display_vid }}</div>
        <div>Created: {{ display_created }}</div>
        <div>Updated: {{ diplay_updated }}</div>```

The examples I have found have shown how to build forms and use text fields/text areas, but nothing for a plain HTML page.

Anybody got suggestions?

Thanks.
Jeff Brown
````

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the data attribute from the `JsonResponse` object, for example:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse


def my_view(request):
    data = {'display_uid': 'some data',
            'display_vid': 'some other data'} # add more items to the dictionary
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: Thanks SLDem. I have the HTTP/Python dictionary part. What I am looking for is using Django how to I get the responses into the HTML. As per the bottom snippet above I have attempted to use Django variable wrapping technique of double opening and closing braces, but no luck in getting the data displayed on the page.

Comment: You will have to use your frontend framework to do a request to this view function and then process the data in JavaScript and display it on the template.

Comment: If you are not planning to use frontend frameworks then you should use regular template render method with context.